# CSS Target pseudo-class not changing DIV properties

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I'd like to change the property of one DIV when a different one is targeted.

Here's my CSS:

```
#boards-list:target{
    background-color: black;
}
#boards-list:target  div#schools-list{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="schools-sub-nav">

<a href="#schools-list">Schools List</a> <a href="#boards-list">Boards List</a>

</div>

<div id="schools-container">

    <div id="schools-list">
    One
    </div>

    <div id="boards-list">
    Two
    </div>

</div>
```

My only thought is that I've made a mistake in my syntax for using the target pseudo-class.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what exactly you're looking to achieve...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, do you want the schools list blue and the boards list black? If so, just remove the `boards-list` selector from the second statement? So you should have:

```
#boards-list:target
{
    background-color: black;
}

#schools-list:target
{
     background-color: blue;
}​
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/3dbTq/1**

Comment: To clarify, when `boards-list` is targeted I want to change the background colour of `schools-list`. So it's not a case of setting the colours in the first place, it's a case of changing them when a specific one is targeted.

Comment: Or do they need to be the other way round?

Answer (score 0):

Your last rule:

```
#boards-list:target  div#schools-list       {
                                        background-color: blue;
                                        }
```

Is not going to work, because `boards-list` and `schools-list` are siblings, they are not parent/child.

Change it to:

```
#schools-list:target       {
                                            background-color: blue;
                                            }
```

Comment: To clarify, when `boards-list` is targeted I want also change the background colour of `schools-list`.

Comment: So sorry, I thought it was clear on the first line: "I'd like to change the property of one DIV when a different one is targeted."